# Is REPEATABLE-READ too strict in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, transaction-isolation

Specifically, why their manual claims [following](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html)

> a repeatable read transaction cannot modify or lock rows changed by
>   other transactions after the repeatable read transaction began.

Is that claim really necessary to guarantee absence of "Nonrepeatable Reads" ? It is not obvious for me, could somebody clarify?

Answer (score 3):

That statement applies to `REPEATABLE READ`, not `READ COMMITTED`.

`READ COMMITTED` does *not* enforce the requirement you quoted. Only `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE` do.

The reason a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction cannot modify or lock rows changed by other transactions after it began is because the modified row might no longer match the predicate that the transaction uses to select it, and because the new value (which the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isn't permitted to see) could be lost if the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction then modifies the row based on the old version it can see.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely meant REPEATABLE-READ - I fixed the question. But I still do not understand why that is enforced. E.g. my understanding that postgresql will show an error at step 3 below: 1. Transaction A reads table X 2. Transaction B modifies table Y. 3. Transaction A tries to modify the same rows in table Y.   Is my understanding correct and is raising error really required to satisfy requirement in standard "absence of Nonrepeatable Read"?